# Install Ubuntu on custom LVM

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, lvm

I would like to install Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS on my desktop. My device is SSD 500 Go.

All the unit will be formatted and dedicated to Ubuntu. I'd like to use my device as follows :

```
/dev/sda1 => /boot (500MB)
rootvg on /dev/sda2 (30GB)

=> lv_root (20g ext4) mounted on / in root_vg  
=> lv_swap (8g) for swap on root_vg

vg_home on /dev/sda3 (10g)
=> lv_home (10g ext4) mounted on /home

vg_apps on /dev/sda4 (50g)
=> lv_myapps (40g ext4) mounted on /apps_kerns/
=> lv_mylogs (10g ext4) mounted on /apps_log/
```

Obviously, it is not possible to create Volume Group and Logical Volumes while installing Ubuntu.
Any workaround?
Any ideas?

Comment: Probably easiest to install the server version and then install ubuntu-desktop - https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/advanced-installation.html

Comment: Or run the live system, prepare partitions and start installation selecting pre-prepared partitions.

Answer (score 0):

It is very much possible to have LVM at the time of install itself. Infact that's a preferred way also. Please refer to this [thread](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm)

In case you have already running system - you can have lvm at that time [also](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpLVM-WithoutACleanInstall)